# Add class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to add class to my div. How? Look bottom:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".menu-div").hover(function(){
          $(this).addClass("menu-div-hover");
            });
});
```

```css
.menu-div-hover{
     background-color:#25262A;
}

.menu-div{
          height:50px;
          border-top:;
          border-bottom:;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=""><div class="text-center menu-div">FAQ</div></a>
```

It is my http://jsfiddle.net/pj4oqffu/
What I did wrong? I don't want answers, I need to learn it. If you can help me, please do it :)

Comment: It works , you need to replace 'menu-div-hover ' after 'menu-div'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure why you are using `jquery` for that where you can simply do that using `css`.
But to your problem the solution is you need to add `important` tag to your css as following:

```
.menu-div-hover{
     background-color:#25262A !important;
}
```

Here is the edit of your code example: http://jsfiddle.net/pj4oqffu/3/

But I strongly suggest you do that using plain css as following:

```
.menu-div:hover{
     background-color:#25262A !important;
}
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pj4oqffu/5/

Answer (score 4):

Why use jQuery at all?

Simply use `CSS` and the `:hover` selector:

```
.menu-div:hover{
     background-color:#25262A;
}
```

If you need to do it via jQuery, simply move the `hover` class below the original (Your jQuery code is fine).

```
.menu-div
{
  height:50px;
  border-top:;
  border-bottom:;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.menu-div-hover
{
  background-color:#25262A;
}
```

Which will take precedence, you can also use `!important` on the hover background colour.

http://jsfiddle.net/pj4oqffu/1/

Comment: Nice it is it. Do you know how to do it with jQuery? Its working but I need to know the same in jQuery :)

Comment: your js code was ok, you just have to "override" the class backround property using !important http://jsfiddle.net/pj4oqffu/2/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to user $.hover then you need to set **and remove** the class:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".menu-div").hover(
         function(){
             $(this).addClass("menu-div-hover");
         },
         function(){
             $(this).removeClass("menu-div-hover");
        });
 });
```

Also you need to define `.menu-div-hover` after `.menu-div` in order to overwrite the background-color during hover.